# What is the best way of upserting over 1000000 items to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have over 1000000 words to save to the database and of course, there are lots of the same word in that text. I used lots of way to make it as fastest I can but every time that I tried MongoDB reduces upserting to the DB. Since I just started to work with MongoDB. What would be the fastest way to upserting over 1000000 items to the MongoDB ?

I am trying to upsert with unordered bulk operation. When python application starts, it is inserting 8000 items so quickly but by the time speed of insertion decreases significantly.

```
 bulk = symbols.initialize_unordered_bulk_op();
 for i in dataset:
     bulk.find({'name': i}).upsert().update({'$inc': {'freq': 1}})
 try:
    bulk.execute()
 except BulkWriteError as bwe:
    print bwe.details
 con.close()
```

Comment: As the collection grows, the find becomes more expensive. You need to create an index on the `name` field to make sure the finds are efficient.

Comment: @sirfz Thank you for answering. Can I do indexing during runtime ? for example after slicing dataset into smaller pieces and after each small piece doing indexing on runtime

Comment: Sure, you can also pass the `background=True` argument to make indexing run in the background without disrupting current operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [sirfz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3572366/sirfz) for the recommendation, saved my life. After each data chunk that I inserted to MongoDB, I did indexing than everything becomes so fast.

```
<collection_name>.create_index([("name", pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)
```